# Passing pandas subset of dataframe to lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pass a subset of my dataframe rows — conditioned with `'rating_count' > m` — to the 'weighted_rating' function. However, the passed data contains only the 'user_id' column while it's expected to contain several other columns. As the result I receive the `KeyError` on the line `v = xx['rating_count']` (see the log below).

So, I need `xx['rating_count']` and `xx['rating']` to be present inside the function.

```py
def weighted_rating(xx):  
    print(xx)
    v = xx['rating_count']
    R = xx['rating']
    return (v/(v+m) * R) + (m/(m+v) * C)
  
    final_data['weighted_rating'] = final_data.loc[final_data['rating_count'] >= m].apply(lambda x: weighted_rating(x))
```

**Output:**

```sh
659        user_97032@domain.com
660        user_97032@domain.com
662        user_97032@domain.com
663        user_97032@domain.com
664        user_97032@domain.com
                    ...          
1653167    user_80312@domain.com
1653169    user_80312@domain.com
1653178    user_80312@domain.com
1653179    user_80312@domain.com
1653190    user_80312@domain.com
Name: user_id, Length: 88446, dtype: object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
    3362             except KeyError as err:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'rating_count'
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```sh
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3296/835381681.py in <module>
----> 1 final_data.loc[final_data['rating_count'] >= m].apply(lambda x: weighted_rating(x))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
    8738             kwargs=kwargs,
    8739         )
-> 8740         return op.apply()
    8741 
    8742     def applymap(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply(self)
    686             return self.apply_raw()
    687 
--> 688         return self.apply_standard()
    689 
    690     def agg(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    810 
    811     def apply_standard(self):
--> 812         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    813 
    814         # wrap results

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    826             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    827                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 828                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    829                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    830                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3296/835381681.py in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 final_data.loc[final_data['rating_count'] >= m].apply(lambda x: weighted_rating(x))

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3296/3170994745.py in weighted_rating(xx)
        1 def weighted_rating(xx):
        2     print(xx)
----> 3     v = xx['rating_count']
        4     R = xx['rating']
        5     return (v/(v+m) * R) + (m/(m+v) * C)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    940 
    941         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 942             return self._get_value(key)
    943 
    944         if is_hashable(key):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    1049 
    1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    1053 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
    3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
    3364 
    3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'rating_count'
```

I also tried the following code with no luck:

```py
final_data['weighted_rating'] = final_data[final_data['rating_count'] >= m].apply(lambda x: weighted_rating(x))
```

Am I doing something wrong? Please help

**Edit: Adding sample data**

```html
<div>
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: right;">
            <th></th>
            <th>user_id</th>
            <th>user_age</th>
            <th>gender</th>
            <th>location</th>
            <th>joining_date</th>
            <th>content_id</th>
            <th>duration_user</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>start_time</th>
            <th>end_time</th>
            <th>content_type</th>
            <th>language</th>
            <th>genre</th>
            <th>duration_content</th>
            <th>release_date</th>
            <th>rating</th>
            <th>episode_count</th>
            <th>season_count</th>
            <th>rating_count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <td>user_44289@domain.com</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>Goa</td>
            <td>2018-09-03</td>
            <td>cont_3375_16_10</td>
            <td>2220000.0</td>
            <td>2020-06-03</td>
            <td>18:47:17</td>
            <td>19:24:17</td>
            <td>series</td>
            <td>english</td>
            <td>action</td>
            <td>3060000.0</td>
            <td>2015-11-16</td>
            <td>5.0</td>
            <td>10.0</td>
            <td>16.0</td>
            <td>64</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>user_44289@domain.com</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>Goa</td>
            <td>2018-09-03</td>
            <td>cont_1195_1_8</td>
            <td>900000.0</td>
            <td>2019-04-18</td>
            <td>11:12:40</td>
            <td>11:27:40</td>
            <td>sports</td>
            <td>english</td>
            <td>football</td>
            <td>5400000.0</td>
            <td>2017-03-09</td>
            <td>0.0</td>
            <td>8.0</td>
            <td>1.0</td>
            <td>66</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td>user_44289@domain.com</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>Goa</td>
            <td>2018-09-03</td>
            <td>cont_3470_2_15</td>
            <td>1620000.0</td>
            <td>2021-09-18</td>
            <td>11:55:34</td>
            <td>12:22:34</td>
            <td>series</td>
            <td>english</td>
            <td>horror</td>
            <td>2820000.0</td>
            <td>1997-08-05</td>
            <td>8.0</td>
            <td>15.0</td>
            <td>2.0</td>
            <td>63</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>3</th>
            <td>user_44289@domain.com</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>Goa</td>
            <td>2018-09-03</td>
            <td>cont_310_25_9</td>
            <td>780000.0</td>
            <td>2020-08-09</td>
            <td>11:38:44</td>
            <td>11:51:44</td>
            <td>series</td>
            <td>english</td>
            <td>comedy</td>
            <td>3960000.0</td>
            <td>2019-06-29</td>
            <td>4.0</td>
            <td>9.0</td>
            <td>25.0</td>
            <td>62</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <td>user_44289@domain.com</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>Goa</td>
            <td>2018-09-03</td>
            <td>cont_4350_1_3</td>
            <td>3480000.0</td>
            <td>2021-06-25</td>
            <td>23:42:44</td>
            <td>00:40:44</td>
            <td>sports</td>
            <td>english</td>
            <td>cricket</td>
            <td>3840000.0</td>
            <td>2002-10-21</td>
            <td>0.0</td>
            <td>3.0</td>
            <td>1.0</td>
            <td>66</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: please share a sample of your data

Comment: @TomerS yes shared it above under my Edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to apply `weighted_rating()` to each row of the dataframe `final_data`. In order to do that, you need to pass `axis=1` to apply() method.

```
final_data['weighted_rating'] = final_data[final_data['rating_count'] >= m].apply(lambda x: weighted_rating(x), axis=1)
```

ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html